# best pattern for authorization in cas based web app?

Tags: jakarta-ee, active-directory, glassfish, authorization, cas

My Java EE application is deployed on Glassfish 3.2.1 and authentication is demanded to a CAS server. CAS server returns into the principal a list of all Active Directory groups the authenticated user belongs to. Extending javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper I'm able to override the getUserInRole method which search for the role in the list.
It works correctly but the assumption is:

- AD groups and roles are the same (one to one correspondence)
- so roles are not defined by the application: they have to be defined
  as AD groups
- so groups in AD are becoming quite a big.

The last point is crucial because when other applications use the same Authorization mechanism and needs several roles, the number of AD groups increases a lot and the time spent by getUserInRole function increases as well.

So, even if this authorization method works well for few roles and few applications, it could have performance problems in case of several applications with several roles each.

Now the question: Is there another pattern I can use to overcome the performance issue with the following constraints? CAS authentication, GlassFish, Java EE application.

Comment: @ewernli: what do you mean with caching? Could you elaborate please ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29

Comment: @ewernli: sorry, I know what caching means, but from your elaborated comment It's still unclear to me how that could answer my question.